Postgres RLS update conditions not met when column RLS relies on is updated
I have a Postgres Database with a single table profile in it. This table has two columns, an id and a username. I've enabled RLS and have applied the following policies.
 schemaname | tablename |         policyname          | permissive |  roles   |  cmd   |                            qual                            | with_check 
------------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 public     | profile   | select_user_or_group_policy | PERMISSIVE | {public} | SELECT | (current_setting('myapp.username'::text, true) = username) | 
 public     | profile   | unrestricted_insert         | PERMISSIVE | {public} | INSERT |                                                            | true
 public     | profile   | unrestricted_update         | PERMISSIVE | {public} | UPDATE | true                                                       | true
 public     | profile   | unrestricted_delete         | PERMISSIVE | {public} | DELETE | true                                                       | 

myapp.username is set by an external application but for testing purposes gets set by calling
select set_config('myapp.username', 'user1', false);.
When selecting data from the DB I see it work as expected, only returning the rows where the username matches the myapp.username config. When updating though I'd expect the policy to allow me to update any record I can see at the start of the update. I'd like to be able to change the username to a different user, but I get the following error when doing so. I'm confused because the update policy is set to USING (true) WITH CHECK (true).
Table before update (the table has a primary key on the id column and no restrictions on the other column.



id
username




1
user1


2
user2



UPDATE profile SET username = 'user2' WHERE id = 1;
ERROR:  new row violates row-level security policy for table "profile"


The problem is that the SELECT policy is also used to check the new row, so that you cannot perform an update that would make a row seem to vanish.
See the comments in the source (function get_row_security_policies() in src/backend/rewrite/rowsecurity.c):
/*
 * Get and add ALL/SELECT policies, if SELECT rights are required for
 * this relation (eg: when RETURNING is used).  These are added as WCO
 * policies rather than security quals to ensure that an error is
 * raised if a policy is violated; otherwise, we might end up silently
 * dropping rows to be added.
 */


Interesting, I thought that was the whole point of having the USING and WITH CHECK portions of the UPDATE RLS policy. One is used to check the row before the update and one after, specifically so that it could have a different policy than the SELECT policy.

I find that row-level security with statements other than SELECT is a mine field.
